# My functions return 'undefined'

Tags: javascript

```
function countOddNumbers(anArray1) {
    var counter;
    var anArray1 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < anArray1.length; i++) {
        if (anArray1[i] % 2 == 0) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

function countEvenNumbers(anArray2) {
    var anArray2 = [];
    var counter2;
    for (var i = 0; i < anArray2.length; i++) {
        if (anArray2[i] % 2 != 0) {
            counter2++;
        }
    }
    return counter2;
}
var theArray = new Array(5);
for (var i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++) {
    theArray[i] = window.prompt("please enter a number", " ");
}
document.write(theArray);
document.write(countOddNumbers(theArray));
document.write(countEvenNumbers(theArray));
```

I am getting the `theArray` printed on the screen but am not getting the result of the two functions called, I am getting "undefined". Is the problem in the functions or in their calls? I am not able to find the error.

Comment: in your functions, you override the arrays that you pass into the functions.

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies because inside each function you redeclare the parameter (either `anArray1` or `anArray2`) and set it to an empty array.

You then try to loop through an empty array, which doesn't do anything, and return the uninitialised value of `counter`, which is logically `undefined`.

EDIT: As @blex pointed out correctly, you will need to also make sure you initialise the counter variable to `0` so when you increment it using `counter++`, it won't give you `NaN` (Not A Number).

Comment: **+1**. That's a start, but he also needs to initialize the counters to 0, or he'll get `NaN`: http://jsfiddle.net/49apz1nv/